# Custom Django Login returning 'OK'

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-login

I'm currently creating my own custom Django login page. Here is my view:

```
def login_poster(request):
     state = "Verified Posters, please login below..."
     username = password = ''
     if request.POST:
         username = request.POST.get('username')
         password = request.POST.get('password')

         user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
         if user:
                  if user.is_active:
                 login(request, user)
                 state = "You're successfully logged in!"   
             else:
                 state = "You must have a verified Poster account to login."
         else:
             state = "Your username and/or password were incorrect."
     return render_to_response('poster_login.html',{'state':state, 'username': username})
```

and this is my template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Log in</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style>
body{
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
{{ state }}
<form action="/login/" method="post">
    {% if next %}
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
    {% endif %}
    username:
    <input type="text" name="username" value="{{ username}}" /><br />
    password:
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" /><br />

    <input type="submit" value="Log In" />
</form>
```

For some reason, whenever I log in with the wrong username and password or the right username and password AND with empty fields, I get the following response in my browser,

```
OK
```

It just keeps showing OK no matter what I enter. It is not even checking to see if the credentials are invalid. Once I press submit, regardless of whatever is in the fields, it still returns 'OK'

I followed this tutorial: http://solutoire.com/2009/02/26/django-series-1-a-custom-login-page/

How can one go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you are getting the OK page.  However, I used your code with "render" replacing "render_to_response":

render(request, 'poster_login.html',{'state':state, 'username': username})

And with "csrf_token" in your template:

{% csrf_token %}
...

Doing this gives the expected result on my setup.

Comment: @GeorgeOctavianRavanc I'll give your way a try, where did you place the csrf_token?

Comment: You have to add the csrf_token anywhere inside your form tag:  <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %} ..... </form>